# Using TLS for authentication vs API token

Tags: web-services, apache, authentication, ssl, x509

I'm creating a SOA system, where server A connects to server B via SSL/TLS.

I could use an API token to ensure A is who they say they are.  But since I'm using TLS, and server A has a Verisign issued X.509 certificate that says who they are, it seems to make sense to use the certificate.

So the high-level authentication workflow would be:

- A connects to B by TLS
- B checks checks A's certificate
- B drops A if the cert is invalid OR if the cert is for any other party than A

I'd like to do this at outside of the application, at the lowest level of the network stack possible.  Possibly by an Apache config directive that would say something like:

```
DropUnlessX509CertificateNameMatches XXXXXXXXX
```

?

Are there any drawbacks to this vs API token authentication?

Comment: Server-side certificate will have key usage set to "Authenticate as server" and for correct authentication and validation you need it to have "authenticate as client". Of course if you validate the certificate in code, you can skip the check of KeyUsage property.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by setting key usage to "authenticate as server" or client.  Where would I set that?  In Apache?  In the cert somehow?

Comment: These are properties of the certificate (i.e. flags in KeyUsage certificate extension). You can't set them - they are set by the CA from which you purchase the certificate.

Comment: Hmmm interesting.  Not sure this will work in our case, since we have existing certificates that are already issues and distributed.

Comment: If you have custom validation mechanism on server B, then you can ignore the check of KeyUsage property. But this is not possible if you want validation to be automatic (i.e. done without programming).

Comment: I decided just to devolve to an API token, as its more easy to automate testing around anyway.  Thanks for your suggestions Eugene.